# Google cloud server is slow when there is high network traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a google compute engine server that runs slowly when there is high network traffic, what do I need to upgrade to improve the speed?

Comment: Based upon the details in your question, there are three primary factors for performance. CPU, Memory, and Disk IOPS. Select a larger instance size which usually increases the RAM as well. Resize the disk larger which increases the disk performance (IOPS). The best method is too monitor your system for bottlenecks so that you know what to change/modify.

Comment: @JohnHanley CPU usage is below 20% , memory usage is below 10% and disk space is at 25% so I am not confident increasing them will help?

Comment: That data should have been in your original question. However, free disk space is not the item regarding disk performance. Google scales disk IOPS based upon disk size, not free space. Your question does not have details to create a good answer.

Comment: As John mentioned, disk performance is limited by its total size, not available space. You can read more here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance. You can use Cloud Monitoring to inspect the disk IO usage.